# Unique taxonomy input in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, unique, taxonomy

I have registered a taxonomy named " sku " in my wordpress function.php.

```
register_taxonomy( 'sku', 'post', array( 'hierarchical' => false,  'label' => 'SKU', 'query_var' => false, 'rewrite' => true,'public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'revisions' => false,'publicly_queryable' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'show_in_nav_menus' => true ));
```

But I want to input a unique sku value for each post. Please somebody give me a solution how can I make it ?

Answer (score 1):

you can trigger this function on `save_post` hook

something like ..

```
 function dynamic_term( $term) {
    register_taxonomy( '$term', 'post', array( 'hierarchical' => false,  'label' => '$term', 'query_var' => false, 'rewrite' => true,'public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'revisions' => false,'publicly_queryable' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'show_in_nav_menus' => true ));

    }
    add_action( 'save_post', ' dynamic_term' );

`$term` variable will be dynamic which you will pass unique for each post
```

Comment: Dear wordpresser, I am newbie to wordpress and I don't know how to trigger this function and use your solution in my site. If you don't mind please help me how I can use it?

Comment: put this in your functions.php it should work. but in order to give unique taxonomy to each post you have to pass `$term` variable which will be unique for you each post .. that depends on you what taxonomy you want to assign and how you will dynamically generate.. this piece of code will be called each time you will publish any post or update it

Answer (score 0):

But Where will you define the taxonomy names ?
If any other taxonomies are defined in function.php which are not dynamic!